# Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix Plus Symmetric Matrix is again Positive Definite

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $|| \cdot ||$ be a matrix norm (need not to be induced or submultiplicative), $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ a symmetric, positive definite, (therefore invertible) matrix and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be just a symmetric matrix.

Show that if
$$
||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||B|| < 1
$$
then $A + B$ is positive definite.

Hint: If $t \mapsto A(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a continuous function, there are continuous functions which maps $t$ to each Eigenvalues of $A$.

---

I just don't have much of an idea where to start. Since the norm need not to be submultiplicative, I can't say $||A^{-1}|| \geq (||A||)^{-1}$. I don't know how to use the hint and using the diagonalization of the matrices doesn't seem to help.

EDIT: The things I wrote below, I don't think that even holds because you probably need again the submultiplicative property to conclude that.

Only thing I noticed was that $$
||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||B|| < 1 \\
\Rightarrow ||D_{A^{-1}}|| \cdot ||D_B|| < 1
$$

where $D_{A^{-1}}$ and $D_B$ are the diagonal form of the matrices with Eigenvalues as their entries, but since the norm is not induced, I don't know how this could help.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This isn't true. For any matrices $A$ and $B$, we can always pick a norm such that $\|A^{-1}\|\|B\|<1$ (e.g. pick $\|X\|=\epsilon\|X\|_F$ for some sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$), but clearly, $A+B$ is not always positive definite.

Comment: Thank you and I think you are right. The problem didn't specify it, but the given norm must be induced (and submultiplicative). I'll try to prove the statement with that condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, this is not true for a general matrix norm. We can develop an elementary proof and see what assumptions come up. We will show, using the hint, that if $A+B$ is not SPD, then $\|A^{-1}\|\|B\|\geq 1$.

Assume that $A+B$ is not positive definite, that is, it has at least one non-positive eigenvalue. Let $f(t):=A+tB$ where $t$ is a real scalar. Note that $A=f(0)$ is positive definite and $A+B=f(1)$ is not. Since the eigenvalues of $f$ are continuous functions of $t$, there is a $t_*\in(0,1]$ such that $f(t_*)$ has a zero eigenvalue.

Let $\|\cdot\|_$ be a vector norm.
There exists an $x$ such that $\|x\|_=1$ and $(A+t_*B)x=0$, so $x=-t_*A^{-1}Bx$ and 
$$
1=\|x\|_=|t_*|\|A^{-1}Bx\|_\leq\|A^{-1}Bx\|_.
$$
Now if a matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_$ is [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Consistent_norms) with the vector norm $\|\cdot\|_$, we have that
$$
1\leq\|A^{-1}B\|_.
$$

This means that if $\|A^{-1}B\|_<1$, then $A+B$ is SPD.

If you add sub-multiplicativity to your assumptions on the matrix norm, a sufficient condition is that $$\|A^{-1}\|_\|B\|_<1.$$